# remove string between brackets

Tags: php, regex

In PHP, how to remove string between Active/End Date parenthesis?

For example:

```
$String1  = "Text Text - (Active Date: 12-03-2011 , End Date:12-03-2013)";
$String2  = "Free Free Text Text(2000 min)-Ret - (Active Date: 12-03-2011 , End Date: )";
```

I want `$String1` to replace to: "Text Text"

and `$String2` to "Free Free Text Text(2000 min)-Ret"

Comment: Can you have nested brackets like this: `"Text Text - (Active Date: 12-03-2011 , (FOO) End Date:12-03-2013)"` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do.

```
$pattern = '/\s*\-\s*\(\s*Active[^\)]+\)/';
$String1 = preg_replace($pattern, '', $String1);
$String2 = preg_replace($pattern, '', $String2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use something like:

```
preg_replace('/\(Active.*?\)/','(text Text)',$String1);
```

Note that the parenthesis need to be escaped with `\` so they are interpreted as literals, not as control characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
substr( $string, 0, strpos($string," - (") );
```

**Edit:** After, you may use `trim()` for stripping whitespaces from begin and end of the string.

Comment: Use [strrpos](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php) instead to make sure you get the last occurrence.